# TYPO3, Extbase, Paginate

Tags: pagination, typo3, view-helpers, typo3-6.1.x

I am developing a simple Extbase/Fluid extension for TYPO3 CMS 6.1.17. It works fine, but I am not able to implement a ViewHelper to paginate.

Looking around, I tried to hack some code from [News](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news). However I fail to see how (and where) I have to set my TS.

I tried (setup.ts)

```
plugin.tx_myext.view.widget.Myvendor\Myext\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

but then I get error:

```
Could not analyse class:Myvendor\Myext\ViewHelpers\HeaderDataViewHelper maybe not loaded or no autoloader?
```

which I do not know how to fix. If I try:

```
plugin.tx_myext.view.widget.Myvendor\Myext\ViewHelpers\Widget\PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Templates/ViewHelpers/Widget/Controller/index.html
```

I get the FE error:

```
No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "index" in class "Myvendor\Myext\ViewHelpers\Widget\Controller\PaginateController"
```

If you spot what I am not seeing, please let me know.

thanks 
mario

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use pagination for your custom records than simply use js_paginate extension from typo3 repository http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/js_paginate

Just follow the procedure from following URL

https://github.com/jainishsenjaliya/js_paginate/blob/master/readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**
When hacking a template for Pagination from News, I overlooked to note occurences of the tag `<n:headerData>`. To get it parsed, I need to cut&paste corresponding `HeaderDataViewHelper.php` into my ext.

:-)